# Some Selenium tests fail on server but pass locally

Tags: selenium, selenium2

i'd like to know if anyone faced the following problem with Selenium tests run:
when scripts are running locally all tests pass, but when they are ran on server for the same site some of tests fail (different tests every day without script changes).
The most interesting thing is that if i watch the process on server all tests pass.

Does anyone know what can be the reason and how to fix it? Or at least how to investigate it?

Scripts are running for Firefox browser.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any patterns to the failures?  Are they failing with the same or similar exceptions?  Can you provide us with a sample of the failures?

Comment: yes, in most cases it cannot find element though i have a custom method which waits for element appearance. tests create some new page elements (links, for example) and then try to interact with them. i'm quite sure these elements appear on page but for some reason Selenium doesn't want to see them when scripts are ran on server. locally there are no such problems

Comment: Can you take screenshots on failure?  Being able to see what the screen looked like at the time might give you a hint.

Comment: i'll try, thank you. However i doubt this would help much because the same script is running on both machines and there is no way to guess which test would fail today :)

Comment: that's exactly what makes me think a screenshot might help.  If something external to your tests is interfering, it's likely to leave a visual clue.  I'm thinking there might be something else happening on that server that is obscuring Selenium's ability to interact w/ the browser.

Comment: This is unlikely on a server, but might be worth checking.  Does the computer go into sleep mode or hibernation?  I don't know if/ how that would affect Selenium, but I've had issues w/ UI automation before from this.

Comment: If the server in question is a Windows machine, you could remote-desktop into it to see what it's up to.

Comment: server doesn't go into sleep, and not all but some tests fail (and not last tests). and if i go to server and watch the process - no failures

Comment: i've added a screenshot making code and here is what i got: as i wrote before script creates new page element and tries to interact with it. To create these new elements popup window should be opened, some text should be entered and confirm button should be clicked. The problem is with confirm button. Sometimes after confirm click window doesn't disappear, though click is successfull. I've added stub code to click button twice if it doesn't disappear after first click, and all tests passed. Can anyone suppose what is the problem?

Comment: I know that the thread is old,but if you find an workaround please can you reply it back,i have face a similar problem when running on teamcity server.I found a temporary solution by adding Wait for some elements,although the tests are running fine locally.

Comment: @Melena As per your last comment, it is problem of clicking on button event. The response comes after some time or stuck any time. Without going into the code you can increase RAM and processor to get fast machine speed. More you can identify internet connection as well. Even if you are getting error put some more timeout and sleep for it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a problem I've faced before. Some buttons are dependent on JavaScript binds. If you click the button before the JavaScript loads, the button will not have the bound event. Therefore, Selenium will successfully click on the button (since the DOM is loaded properly) but the JavaScript hasn't bound to that particular button yet. Solutions you can try include waiting for the JavaScript bind on the element or continuously clicking on the element until the correct action is performed.

You can adapt this code as needed:

`'selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().$("#id").data("events").click' != 'null'`